# Pointer to a pointer to array of command-line arguments

Tags: c

Reading code, I see individuals pass command-line arguments to `main()` in two different ways. Often, and the way I choose to do it, is a pointer to an array containing the arguments (`char *argv[]`). I will also see code which uses a pointer to a pointer to the argument(s) instead (`char **argv`).

These seem very similar and I'm not sure whether there is any pragmatic reason for choosing to do this one way or another. Could anybody let me know why?

Comment: The two are equivalent - pick whichever one you like best.

Comment: Your description is not quite correct - it is an array of pointers, not a pointer to an array. One difference is that within the function main, you can assign char** `argv` to a different local intirect string instance, but you can't assign `argv[]` - it is considered const at that level.